# What does the grey color represents in Adobe Scout's Frame Timeline panel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-scout

I was wondering if anybody knows what does the grey color stands for in the Frame Timeline panel in Scout.

[image]

It is explained what are: blue, green, yellow and orange colors, but I can't find what does the grey is for? Other, non-flashplayer events? It is almost always higher than any other columns and often higher than my FPS limit so I was wondering if it is something that slows down my apps performance and if I can affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it represents 'inactive' times between AVM's next time slice is processed. mostly consists of waiting GPU for rendering (only in rendermode=gpu or rendermode=direct) after uploading all data to GPU, or simply waiting for next frame, etc.

With proper load balance, the grey portion of frame time won't hurt your app's performance.